# Trane furnace pilot wont stay lit

Tags: hvac

I have a 1983 Trane gas furnace, Model BLU108E936B1, the pilot light went out, I could get it to relight but wont stay on> Changed the thermocouple, same results, Pilot light doesn't look right as I recall before, the flame doesn't seem to come up as high as before to hit the thermocouple correctly. I tried different positions for the flame to hit thermocouple but still same results, Pilot wont stay lit.

Comment: How long did you keep your finger on the light pilot button?  Some pilots take a good minute, or even two or three, before they stay lit.  (It can feel like a long time to lie in an uncomfortable position with your finger on the light pilot button.)

Comment: NYC thanks for the reply. I had the button down a long time. Furnace been working fine, noticed getting cold, checked and pilot wasn't lit. Tried many times, it would lite, Burner come on and pilot goes out

Answer (score 1):

I would still not trust the thermocouple. I encourage you to just take the new thermocouple back out, and re-install it. I had this exact same problem and unfortunately paid a contractor to come out and do just that, and somehow it fixed it. I guess the things are just finicky.

There should also be a way to adjust the pilot light's flame, typically a screw.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It ended up being my outside gas meter was sticking not letting the gas supply get to my furnace all the time, that's why it would work sometimes and then shut down again. Gas company came out and replaced the meter.